# Ubuntu system logs written to ".log.1" instead of ".log" after rotation

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, rsyslog, logrotate

I have an EC2 instance on AWS with Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS where system logs are written into ".log.1" instead of ".log" (e.g. /var/log/auth.log.1 instead of /var/log/auth.log).

This is what it says in logrotate.conf:

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# use the syslog group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root syslog

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp, or btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0660 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be configured here
```

When I restart syslog (`service rsyslog restart`) the logs start to be written into ".log". But once the file rotates it reverts back to ".log.1".

How can I fix this issue so that logs continue to be written into ".log" after rotation?

I know little about Linux. So please apologize if there is an obvious solution that I haven't come across yet.

EDIT: Adding the content of /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog

```
/var/log/syslog
{
        rotate 7
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        compress
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
        endscript
}

/var/log/mail.info
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/user.log
/var/log/lpr.log
/var/log/cron.log
/var/log/debug
/var/log/messages
{
        rotate 4
        weekly
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
        endscript
}
```

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has been end of life since 2021. Upgrade to a supported release. Chances are that it comes with an improved logrotate config that solves your issue.

Comment: Do you have a `rsyslog` config file in your `/etc/logrotate.d` directory? If yes, please share the content of it. That's the config that usually handles the logrotation of `auth.log`.

Comment: @eDonkey Just added  /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog to the post

Answer (score 0):

> where system logs are written into ".log.1"

Looking at your config, I suspect your description of the issue might not be accurate. Gerald is right - you really should be upgrading the host OS, but meanwhile....

Most daemons will hold an open file handle on log files for performance reasons. The file itself can be renamed - as appears to be happenning here, but an open file handle still points to the same data stream.

The config for (w|b)tmpdoes not have a postrotate script which is used to tell the thing writing the log files that they should close and reopen them.

It appears that *most* of the files in /var/log do have a post-rotate script. So something is going very wrong if these are impacted.

I see no config here for auth.log which on my local system is in /var/log and handled by rsyslog (I checked in /etc/rsyslog.conf). However something must be renaming this file.

You probably just need to find the config on your host which you've not shown us here and add....

```
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
        endscript
```